# MySQL Set session variable during database import

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a database and during that process I want to utilize this command and variable

`set session sql_require_primary_key=0;`

The issue is because I am doing the import from a command line I dont know how to set that variable during the import only.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to put session variables into an option file, and [reference that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html) when you run the mysql client to do your import.

For example, save this in a file "require-pk.cnf":

```
[client]
sql_require_primary_key=0
```

Then invoke your client:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=require-pk.cnf < dump.sql
```

An alternative method is to concatenate the `set` statement with your dump and pipe that to the mysql client:

```
( echo "set sql_require_primary_key=0;" ; cat dump.sql ) | mysql
```

Or of course you could open the dump.sql file in a text editor and add that line near the top.

Note that `sql_require_primary_key` defaults of OFF (0) already, so unless the server you are importing to has enabled it deliberately, you don't need to disable it. If the database administrator has enabled it on purpose, they might have a good reason to do so.